# (gcloud.tasks.queues.create) PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied on 'locations/asia-south1'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, task-queue, google-cloud-tasks

I am trying to create a cloud task queue as guided in [docs](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-queues), but i am getting the below error while creating it

```
ERROR: (gcloud.tasks.queues.create) PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied on 'locations/asia-south1' (or it may not exist).
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo
  domain: googleapis.com
  metadata:
    consumer: projects/projectName
    location: locations/asia-south1
    service: cloudtasks.googleapis.com
  reason: LOCATION_TAX_POLICY_VIOLATED
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help
  links:
  - description: Please sign up with your local Google entity.
```

Comment: Do you have and Organization Policy restricting locations? https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/defining-locations Does your billing or payment account have restrictions?

Comment: @JohnHanley No we don't have any organization Policy restricting locations and also for billing accounts too

Comment: LOCATION_TAX_POLICY_VIOLATED is now documented: https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/proto-google-common-protos/latest/com.google.api.ErrorReason See this answer for one explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68662241/8016720