# Unable to deploy firebase cloud functions to asia-south1

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have been trying to deploy cloud functions to asia-south1 because that is where my firestore is located and it is also the closest to my users. However, my deployment keeps failing if I set the region as asia-south1.

I tried other regions (us-west1, asia-east2, asia-southeast1) and those work just fine. Here's the output I get when trying to deploy to asia-south1:

```
⚠  functions: failed to create function projects/<project-name>/locations/asia-south1/functions/createChat
```

According to [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations) cloud functions are supported in asia-south1 but at the bottom it recommends using asia-east2 if the firestore is in asia-south1.

Is the documentation out of date or are cloud functions just not supported in asia-south1? If neither of those is the case, what might I be doing wrong that is preventing the deployment on asia-south1?

This is the error message that shows up in debug logs:

```
Error during create for projects/<project-name>/locations/asia-south1/functions/dismissChat: HTTP Error: 403, Permission denied on 'locations/asia-south1' (or it may not exist).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the errors are very cryptic and the problem is with the billing account currency. If the `firebase deploy --debug --only functions` command gives a `"LOCATION_TAX_POLICY_VIOLATED"` error it could be because you are in the same region that you are deploying the code to and your billing currency is not the same as the local currency.

I had my billing currency set as USD along with my Indian Tax information. From the looks of a serverfault thread I found, this seems to be the case when you are in South Korea and try deploying with a non KRW billing account as well.

**The solution: go into your billing account and create a new one with the currency being your local currency, then try deploying again.**